# EntityManager entityManager.persist(employee) doesn't save record in database table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am using Spring 3 and Hibernate 4

I have the following in DAO class

```
public void create(PersistEmployeee employee){      
        entityManager.persist(employee);

    }
```

However nothing is saved in database.

I have tried adding `@Transactional` to method `create`, didn't work, added `@Transactional` in my DAO class, didn't work either. I have `@Transactional(readOnly = false)` in EmployeeServiceImpl class, but that didn't help.

I have the following in applicationContext.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Why do you have two transaction managers? I'm not sure about the effects of duplicating the `annotation-driven` element, but I guess it's asking for trouble.

Comment: @zagyi Oh my bad, Thanks, I removed the first one and its corresponding bean, seems to have fixed the issue. If you could post an answer I will be glad to accept it.

Comment: Added my comment as answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you have two transaction managers? I'm not sure about the effects of duplicating the `annotation-driven` element, but I guess it's asking for trouble.